# pod name with url in podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile

I see certain pod files mentioning the pods with just its name (pod 'podName') but certain pods along with its git url (pod 'podName' , :git => 'open source git url')... I also tend to have one such case where I got error when I mention the pod just by its name and without its git url..
So what difference does it really make ? 
"*pod 'podName'*" vs "*pod 'podName' , :git => 'open source git url'*" in pod file ?
For certain pods if I just do a pod install with just the pod name that was just giving out some error which seems to be working only along with its git url. So when is that actually required to specify the git url and when not to ?

Comment: By default, podfile have a basic "URL", that they search with only the podname. But sometimes, with differents ones ("unregistered", private, etc) you might need to specify the Git url. That's mainly the reason. Also, sometimes, you want to point out a specific commit (because others are broken for instance).

Comment: when you add the url is because by example you need to use a different branch instead of default which is master

Answer (score 5):

With URL you can specify fork, branch, tag or commit.

> Sometimes you may want to use the bleeding edge version of a Pod, a
>   specific revision or your own fork. If this is the case, you can
>   specify that with your pod declaration.
>
> To use the master branch of the repo: 
>   pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'
>
> To use a different branch
>   of the repo: pod 'Alamofire', :git =>'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'dev'
>
> To use
>   a tag of the repo: 
>   pod 'Alamofire', :git =>
>   'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '3.1.1'
>
> Or specify a commit: pod 'Alamofire', :git =>
>   'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :commit => '0f506b1c45'

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#from-a-podspec-in-the-root-of-a-library-repo

Answer (score 1):

By adding the `git` parameter, you can specify a specific git repository of the pod library that should be used as a base code. In that case the pod will use the source code from the git repository instead of the version submitted to the pod server.

Read the [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) to learn more, there are several cases in which you would want to use `git` parameter instead of official pod version:

> Sometimes you may want to use the bleeding edge version of a Pod, a specific revision or your own fork.